# fitnesse csv file

Tags: fitnesse

I'm working on trying out fitnesse on a module that does csv file validation like checking if file has read permission, well formed, and have column and data. I've seen fitnesse usually used with specific data entry like username/password or math equations. Just wondering, is it still a good idea to use fitnesse for csv file validation(s)? I think you can use query to load the csv file to fitnesse but not sure how fitnesse will fit in with permission check , etc.

Thanks!

Comment: This will work, fitness can do amazing things :) Just write the page for it. Also, may be simple unit test will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the work here will be building the fixture. Something like this

```
class CSVFileValidatorFixture {
  CSVFileValidatorFixture(String filename) {
  bool fileExists()
  bool fileIsValid()
  string readCell(int row, int column)
  // ...
}
```

will work well for a slim style of tests